# Emacs startup, how to spawn windows and buffers

Tags: emacs

I switched from sublime to emacs and I love it. Org mode is a must-have for me and I would like to customize my emacs startup with it.

I usually work like this :

```
______________
|         | B |
|         |___|
|    A    | C |
|         |___|
|         | D |
|_________|___|
```

A: scratch and files
B: display calendar
C: display org global todolist (or agenda view)
D: my todofile

What I would like, is to have this configuration when I start emacs.
So I need to create the 3 windows at the right, and summon the 3 buffers in.

I would also like to "lock" these windows, I mean, to avoid context buffer to remplace one of these 3 windows.

Could you suggest me something ?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you need [tiling.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/tiling.el) and [grid layout](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GridLayout) ; you may combine both to fit your needs

then, check window registers in manual to lock the layout

Answer (score 0):

You can set in your .emacs file something like this:

```
(split-window-horizontally)
(other-window 1)
(calendar)
(split-window-vertically)
(other-window 1)
(org-mode)
(split-window-vertically)
(other-window 1)
(find-file "/path/to/your/file")
```

Something in this direction will work.